# Finding position of key in list column of a table

Tags: list, kdb, q-lang

I have a table with one of columns `keyname` being `int` and another column `keylist` being `list` of `int`. I am trying to create another column which is position of `keyname` in `keylist` in my table in following manner:

```
update keypos:{y?x} . (keyname;keylist) from tableName
```

OR

```
update keypos:{{x?1}(y=x)} . (keyname;keylist) from tableName
```

Both of these result in `keypos` with value=size of table.

Any insights much appreciated.

Comment: The reason it's returning "size of table" is because you're performing a single lookup of the whole keyname list into the list of lists. But the whole keyname list isn't in the list of lists and so it's returning the out-of-bounds index (which so happens to be equal to the count of the table). Kdb then converts this single atom into a vector to make it a valid column. I think what you're trying to do is do a lookup of *each* keyname into *each* list. Which explains why an each-both is needed

Comment: Thanks @terrylynch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update keypos:keylist?'keyname from tableName
```

Comment: Thanks Akash. This works. Can you shed some light why each both is needed when this works in non- table settings.

Comment: It's because table columns are implemented as lists, making each-both appropriate. In non-table usage keypos is a scalar. So keypos is actually a list of ints and keylist is a list of lists of ints

Comment: Thanks @JamesLittle